# SQL query works in console but not in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Hi im having issues with a sql query it works perfect in console, but when i implement into python it seems to work perfect no errors but when i check the database it hasnt worked, yet with the console it does work the same no errors yet when i check db the data is there... exact same query i use.

Any ideas?

```
UPDATE ex SET fbsiteurl = stringvarible, fbsitesource = '' WHERE id = 23123;
```

in python:

```
 cur = con.cursor()
 sqlquery = "UPDATE ex SET fbsiteurl = '"+somevarible+"', fbsitesource =        '"+somevarible+"' WHERE id = %d;" % recordid                                
 print sqlquery
 cur.execute(sqlquery)
```

query shows up fine in print no issues, if i copy the print out and paste it into a mysql console it works perfect everytime, just come python it acts like it works but dosnt really 0_o

Comment: Please don't add strings together to create your query. That's incredibly dangerous. Read your database library's documentation on "parameterized queries". For instance, that might be written as "sqlquery = 'UPDATE ex SET fbsiteurl = %s, fbsitesource= %s WHERE id = %s'; cur.execute(sqlquery, (somevariable, anothervariable, recordid))". This is critically important!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

connection.autocommit(), or you need to do connection.commit()

Comment: This worked for me as well, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Been there :) you need to close the cursor

Comment: closing the curser didnt help, how very strange this all is.

Answer (score 0):

This little gotcha continues to this day. Just to clarify, I had to use both of the above answers, as in:

```
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        try:
            cur.execute(sqlcommand)
            self.db.commit()
            res = cur.fetchall()
        except res is not None:
            print(res)
        finally:
            cur.close()
```