# A query that works in MySQL terminal fails when executed via PyMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I've provided three sample SQL queries below. Each of these works fine, returning the expected table output when executed directly from terminal in the `MySQL [db] >` environment.

Each other these queries is saved in a python doc called `queries.py`. The second two queries work fine when passed to the db via `pymysql`, but the first one returns an empty array.

I've checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489396/mysql-connector-python-query-works-in-mysql-but-not-python), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705450/sql-query-works-in-console-but-not-in-python), and [this post](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/399) and none of them seem to be addressing the issue.

Here's the sample code that I'm using to test in Python (version `3.5`):

```
import pymysql
import params 
import queries 

conn = pymysql.connect(
  host = params.HOST,
  user = params.USER,
  password = params.PWD,
  db = 'db',
  charset='utf8',
  cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
  autocommit = True)

test_queries = [queries.VETTED, queries.CREATED, queries.CLOSED_OPPS]
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    for query in test_queries: 
        cursor.execute(query)
        print(cursor.fetchall())

() #..blank output -- doesn't make sense because corresponding query works in MySQL env
[...] #..expected output from query 2
[...] #..expected output from query 3
```

Here's what `queries.py` looks like. Each of those queries returns expected output when executed in MySQL, but the first one, `VETTED`, returns a blank array when passed to the DB via `pymysql`:

```
VETTED = """
SELECT
  date_format(oa.logged_at, '%Y-%m-%d')  as `action_date`,
  count(1) `count`
FROM
  crm_audit_field oaf,
  crm_audit oa,
  crm_sales_lead lead
WHERE
  oa.id = oaf.audit_id AND
  oaf.field = 'status' AND
  (
    oaf.new_text = 'Qualified' OR
    oaf.new_text = 'Disqualified' OR
    oaf.new_text = 'Canceled'
  ) AND
  oa.object_class = 'CRM\\Bundle\\SalesBundle\\Entity\\Lead' AND
  lead.id = oa.object_id AND
  (lead.status_id = 'qualified' OR lead.status_id = 'canceled')
GROUP BY
  `action_date`;"""

CREATED = """
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(lead.createdat, '%Y-%m-%d') as `creation_date`,
  count(1)
FROM
  crm_sales_lead `lead`
GROUP BY
  creation_date;"""

CLOSED_OPPS = """
SELECT
  date_format(closed_at, '%Y-%m-%d') `close_date`,
  count(1) `count`
FROM
  crm_sales_opportunity
WHERE
  status_id = 'won'
GROUP BY
  `close_date`;"""
```

Comment: Interesting... It seems like you are using quotes correctly, my humble suggestion would be top simplify your where clause and add conditions gradually.

Comment: Python is chewing up some of your backslash characters in the string literals. You need to double up the backslashes in the string literal in Python.  A total of *four* backslashes, to get *two* backslashes in the SQL text to pass to MySQL, so that MySQL sees it as *one* backslash character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need *four* backslashes in the Python string literal to represent *two* backslash characters needed by MySQL, to represent a backslash character.

MySQL needs *two* backslashes in a string literal to represent a backslash character. The SQL text you have works in MySQL because the string literals contain *two* backslash characters.

But in the Python code, the SQL statement being sent to MySQL contains only *single* backslash characters.

That's because Python also needs *two* backslashes in a string literal to represent a backslash character, just like MySQL does.

So, in Python...

```
  """CRM\\Bundle"""
        ^^
```

represents a string containing only *one* backslash character: **`'CRM\Bundle'`**

To get a string containing *two* backslash characters: **`'CRM\\Bundle'`**

You would need *four* backslashes in the Python literal, like this:

```
  """CRM\\\\Bundle"""
        ^^^^
```

Comment: nailed it, that was exactly the problem. i've seen this before with other apps--should caught it this time around too. thanks!